# An operator $A$ is regular if and only if the $0$ isn't its eigen value.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Proof in my textbook goes: "The equation $A(x) = 0$ has a non-trivial solution if and only if $ \lambda= 0$ is eigenvalue of the operator", but it is not clear to me how that proves the statement.

Comment: Hint: think of the zero vector on the RHS of the equation as $0x$.

Comment: This is simply the definition of eigenvalue, there is (almost) nothing to prove

Comment: This means that you do not understand the definition of "eigenvalue". I recommend you review it.

Comment: It's a good idea to show what you understand from the question and what you tried. That's what this forum encourages

Answer (score 1):

If $A:X\longrightarrow Y$ has $\lambda=0$ as an eigenvalue, then there exists a non-zero $x\in X$ so that $$Ax = 0\cdot x = 0,$$ i.e. there is a non-trivial solution to $Ax = 0$.

On the other hand, if there exists a non-trivial solution $x\in X$, then $$Ax = 0 = 0\cdot x,$$ i.e. $\lambda = 0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.